# Collapse data.table column values while grouping

Tags: r, grouping, data.table

given a `data.table` object I would to collapse the values of some grouped columns into a single object and insert the resulting objects into a new colum.

```
dt <- data.table(
            c('A|A', 'B|A', 'A|A', 'B|A', 'A|B'),
            c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
            c(22.7, 1.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.0)
)
setnames(dt, names(dt), c('GROUPING', 'NAME', 'VALUE'))
dt
#    GROUPING NAME VALUE
# 1:      A|A    0  22.7
# 2:      B|A    0   1.2
# 3:      A|A    1   0.3
# 4:      B|A    1   0.4
# 5:      A|B    0   0.0
```

I think that to do this is first necessary to specify the column for which you want to group, so I should start with something like `dt[, OBJECTS := <expr>, by = GROUPING]`.

Unfortunately, I don't know the expression `<expr>` to use so that the result is as follows:

```
#    GROUPING   OBJECTS
# 1:      A|A  <vector>
# 2:      B|A  <vector>
# 3:      A|B  <vector>
```

Each `<vector>` must contain the values ​​of the other columns. E.g the first `<vector>` have to be a named vector equivalent to:

```
eg <- c(22.7, 0.3)
names(eg) <- c('0', '1')
#    0    1 
# 22.7  0.3
```

Comment: Are you trying to reshape your data.table to wide format?

Comment: your `expr` should look something like `list(list(...))`

Comment: But why? Don't you think this is difficult to work with? Why not reshape it and have columns with values corresponding to `0` and `1`?

Comment: @Arun I know it is difficult to work with, but it is exactly what I need :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* that this is what you are looking for:

```
dt1 <- dt[, list(list(setNames(VALUE, NAME))), by = GROUPING]
dt1
#    GROUPING       V1
# 1:      A|A 22.7,0.3
# 2:      B|A  1.2,0.4
# 3:      A|B        0
str(dt1)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ GROUPING: chr  "A|A" "B|A" "A|B"
# $ V1      :List of 3
#  ..$ : Named num  22.7 0.3
#  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "0" "1"
#  ..$ : Named num  1.2 0.4
#  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "0" "1"
#  ..$ : Named num 0
#  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "0"
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
dt1$V1
# [[1]]
#    0    1 
# 22.7  0.3 
# 
# [[2]]
#   0   1 
# 1.2 0.4 
# 
# [[3]]
# 0 
# 0
```

As @Arun points out in the comments, the "data.table" alternative to `setNames` in this case is `setattr(VALUE, 'names', NAME)`, making another solution:

```
dt1 <- dt[, list(list(setattr(VALUE, 'names', NAME))), by = GROUPING]
```

Comment: I think you should use `setnames`, not `setNames`.

Comment: @Arun, can you show how? There are no old names, so not sure how to go about doing so, so I just used `setNames` from base R.

Comment: Ananda, oh I see. In that case, it's nice to use `setattr(VALUE, 'names', NAME)`

Comment: @Arun, Ananda, `setnames(VALUE,NAME)` _is_ slightly nicer than `setattr(VALUE, 'names', NAME)` as `setnames` checks type and length of the names is correct. The `old` argument has a dual-use, see `?setnames`.

Answer (score 5):

Working inside of `j`:  If you want to have the values of a column be a vector, you need to wrap the output in `list(.)`.

`j` itself requires a call to `list`, so your final expression will resemble a nested `list`, eg:

```
dt[, list(allNames=list(NAME), allValues=list(VALUE)), by=GROUPING]

#    GROUPING allNames allValues
# 1:      A|A      0,1  22.7,0.3
# 2:      B|A      0,1   1.2,0.4
# 3:      A|B        0         0
```

As @Mnel points out, equivalently:

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, list), by=GROUPING]
```

If you want it in long form, then the structure of your `<expr>` will be:
`list( c(  list(), list(), ..., list()  ) )`   eg:

```
dt[, list(c(list(NAME), list(VALUE))), by=GROUPING]

#    GROUPING       V1
# 1:      A|A      0,1
# 2:      A|A 22.7,0.3
# 3:      B|A      0,1
# 4:      B|A  1.2,0.4
# 5:      A|B        0
# 6:      A|B        0
```

Or equivalently:

```
dt[, list(lapply(.SD, c)), by=GROUPING]
```